# Mysql query using straight_join causing less cost but more time to execute

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, query-optimization, database-administration

i am trying to optimize below query which is taking around 1.5 sec to execute.

```
SELECT  id
    FROM  leads
    left join  leads_cstm  ON leads.id = leads_cstm.id_c
    WHERE  deleted=0
      and  cust_temp_id_c = 'xxxx';

*************************** 1. row ***************************

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: leads_cstm
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 696334
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: leads
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_del_user,idx_leads_id_del
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 108
          ref: crmsuite.leads_cstm.id_c
         rows: 1
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I tried creating index on leads_cstm(id_c,cust_temp_id_c) but no luck!! I tried using straight_join as well and cost is reduced but query is now taking more time to execute(3 secs).

```
mysql>  EXPLAIN     SELECT  id
    FROM  leads
    STRAIGHT_JOIN  leads_cstm  ON leads.id = leads_cstm.id_c
    WHERE  deleted=0
      and  cust_temp_id_c = 'xxxxx';


*************************** 1. row ***************************

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: leads
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_del_user,idx_leads_id_del
          key: idx_del_user
      key_len: 2
          ref: const
         rows: 375820
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: leads_cstm
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 108
          ref: crmsuite.leads.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Please suggest why it is taking more time when using straight join and how to optimize this query.

Both tables contains around 750000 rows.

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Done Tim........

Comment: Which table(s) are `deleted` and `cust_temp_id_c` in???  Can't help with optimization without that info.

Comment: Some reason for `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that `deleted` is located in table `leads` and `cust_temp_id_c` in `leads_cstm`.

To optimize this query, try to add these two indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `leads` ADD INDEX `leads_idx_deleted_id` (`deleted`,`id`);
ALTER TABLE `leads_cstm` ADD INDEX `leads_cstm_idx_c_c` (`cust_temp_id_c`,`id_c`);
```

Then run the query:

```
SELECT
        leads.id 
    FROM
        leads 
    LEFT JOIN
        leads_cstm 
            ON leads.id = leads_cstm.id_c 
    WHERE
        leads.deleted = 0 
        AND leads_cstm.cust_temp_id_c = 'xxxx'
```

Comment: although creating the aforesaid indexes did not work,index creation only on column cust_temp_id_c has improved the performance.Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's strange, because the index `leads_cstm_idx_c_c` suggested above also contains `cust_temp_id_c` as the first column, so have that should have the same effect as an index with only `cust_temp_id_c`. Anyway, glad you got this sorted out, good luck :)